# Package tocbasic is used twice when tcolorbox, minted and scrhack is used

Tags: tcolorbox, minted, scrbook

I have problem when I use these packages

```
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}     
\usepackage{scrhack}
```

together with class `scrbook` from Koma-Scripts.

During compile with `lualatex --shell-escape test.tex` the error is occured: **! Package tocbasic Error: file extension `lol' cannot be used twice.**

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}     
\usepackage{scrhack}

\begin{document}
  Hello world
\end{document}
```

How to fix this. I've played around with the order of the packages, but it doesn't help at all.

Comment: You should highlight that there is already a solution, so people can find it quicker

Answer (score 2):

After the carefully reading of the chapter "Improving Third-Party Packages with scrhack" from Koma-script manual I understand that also package listings is modified. And that's why the translation fails. According to the manual, the modification of the package can be switched off by option `listings=false`. This works in my MNWE example.

update: I also succesfully used the solution from [file extension `lol' cannot be used twice #390](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/390) published on Github:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
% Add the following lines, wherever you want.
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{\@ifpackageloaded{minted}{\removefromtoclist[float]{lol}}{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```